# Exit from loop after finding the first positive element in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops

So, need you help, I have loops, where I'd like to find first positive element and it will be text of label and exit from all loops, but every time I get last element:

```
    for j in getArrayOfAllTimes[i].timeForGetDifference()
                {
                    switch j - timeNow() {

                    case let x where x > 0:
                        nextTimeLabel.text = String(j - timeNow())
                        break

                    default:

                        break  
                    }
}
```

How get first element > 0?

Comment: Learn swift  : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html there is nicly explain how to use loop with conditional code

Comment: I didn't got 100%, but is that what are you looking for?

    let ints = [-1, -2, -32, 11, -123, -2, 1, 323]
    
    for currentInt in ints {
         if currentInt > 0 {
          print("\(currentInt) is the first positive number")
          break
         }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `first(where:)` method of `Array`

Instead of explicitly breaking out of a loop when a first element that fulfills som predicate is found, you could simply make use of the `Array` method [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first).

Since you haven't provided us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you should) we'll construct such an example:

```
/* Example setup */
struct Foo: CustomStringConvertible {
    private let bar: Int    

    init(_ bar: Int) { self.bar = bar }

    func timeForGetDifference() -> Int {
        return bar
    }

    var description: String {
        return String(bar)
    }
}

func timeNow() -> Int { return 10 }

let getArrayOfAllTimes = [Foo(6), Foo(2), Foo(9), Foo(4), Foo(11), Foo(3), Foo(13)]

// nextTimeLabel: some UILabel
```

For the example as per above, we could set the `text` property of the `nextTimeLabel` as follows, using `first(where:)` to find the first element fulfilling our predicate, given that it exists (otherwise; will return `nil` in which case we will not enter the optional binding block below).

```
if let firstNonNegativeFoo = getArrayOfAllTimes
    .first(where: { $0.timeForGetDifference() - timeNow() > 0 }) {
    nextTimeLabel.text = String(describing: firstNonNegativeFoo) // 11
}
```

---

As to why your own approach does not work as intended: a `break` statement within a case of a `switch` statement will simply end the execution of the `switch` statement (not the loop which is one level above the `switch` statement.

From the [Language Reference - Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID441):

> **Break Statement**
>
> A `break` statement ends program execution of a loop, an `if` statement,
>   or a `switch` statement.

In you case, you've added the `break` statements as the last statements of each `case`: here, particularly, the `break` has truly no effect (since the `switch` statement would break out anyway, after exiting the `case` which it entered).

```
for i in 1...3 {
    switch i {
        case is Int: print(i); break // redundant 'break'
        case _: ()
    }
} // 1 2 3

// ... the same
for i in 1...3 {
    switch i {
        case is Int: print(i)
        case _: ()
    }
} // 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for j in getArrayOfAllTimes[i].timeForGetDifference() {
      bool a = NO;
                switch j - timeNow() {

                case let x where x > 0:
                    a = YES
                    nextTimeLabel.text = String(j - timeNow())
                    break

                default:

                    break  
                }
     if a == YES {
       break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: u might be getting last 1 becauz only last element matches conditions